# Hiding a div resets page position in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a webpage that is a long document with a navigation pane on the left hand side. The HTML is basically

```
<body style="display:block;">
    <div id="nav-pane" style="width:340px; height:100%; position:absolute;">
         ....
    </div>
    <div id="main-page" style="left:371px; height:100%; position:fixed;">
         ....
    </div>
</body>
```

I have a javascript function to hide the navigation pane for viewing the document on smaller screens, but when I call $("#nav-pane").hide() in IE 8/9, the page view is taken back to the top of the page. Other browsers work fine

edit: style links are fine in the page

The trigger is

```
<div id="close-button" onclick="hideMenu()">
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/images/original/close-button.png">
</div>
```

and the javascript function is

```
function hideMenu()
{
    $("#nav-pane").hide();
}
```

Comment: Are you triggering the hide via clicking on a link with # in the href?

Comment: Please show the markup of the element you're using to trigger hiding the link (if it's in response to a user action), and the actual handler for the event (assuming it's done on an event!).

Comment: Why the downvote? I have the exact same problem, the solution suggested below is not working / helping.

Answer (score 2):

In the absense of further information, a couple of guesses:

#### Guess 1

Is your real code also missing the `"` at the end of the `style` attribute on both divs?

```
<body style="display:block;">
    <!--                                                     here -------v -->
    <div id="nav-pane" style="width:340px; height:100%; position:absolute;>
         ....
    </div>
    <!--                                              and here -------v -->
    <div id="main-page" style="left:371px; height:100%; position:fixed;>
         ....
    </div>
</body>
```

That could cause all sorts of odd things to happen with the parsing of the markup.

#### Guess 2

Your statement saying "Other browsers work fine" is surprising, but:

You haven't shown your code or your markup for how you're triggering it, but I'm guessing you have:

```
<a href="#">the link</a>
```

...and a handler for it:

```
$("selector for the link").click(function() {
    $("#nav-pane").hide();
});
```

You need to prevent the default action of the link you're using to hide the div. In jQuery, you can do that by calling `preventDefault` on the event object it passes to your handler, or `return false;` from the handler (which will prevent the default and stop propagation). E.g.:

```
$("selector for the link").click(function() {
    $("#nav-pane").hide();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[T.J. Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11666132/206614) should solve your issue. However, I have experienced a similar problem with IE. When changing the `display` or `overflow` properties of a parent element the browser would redraw the document and reset the scroll position to 0.

Most probably there is a problem with your markup - as I mentioned in my case it was a parent element (`body` or `html`).

Anyway, to solve this you can record the window scroll position before the hide action and then scroll the window to the recorded position afterwards:

```
var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
// your hide action here, and then:
if ($(window).scrollTop() !== scrollPosition) {
    $(window).scrollTop(scrollPosition);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is the only solution to this i've found so far to this. It's not a markup problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was a problem in my markup. Simply setting the div to display:none in console was enough to reset the window. I have currently got a workaround by setting with the width of the div to 0 and visibility to hidden while I work out if it is Aspose creating the problem when transforming the word file or my program that makes the page from Apsose actually look nice and work properly.

Thanks Guys

Comment: i have the exact same problem. Setting the width to 0 is not an option for me. Do you have any more information about this problem?